# Full Screen Layout For Image View In Compose Without Status And Navigation Bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to view the content or image in full screen by hiding the navigation and status bars as we seen on google photos when the image is clicked on preview it goes to full screen. 
I used `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`  to show the content behind status bar and it works..

but when i hided the system bars the compose container is taking margin or padding from the top and blackout the status bar. I also attached the screenshot in the end

There are less guides available regarding compose on the net

What i was trying currently now

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        //showing the content behind status bar
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                
                //hiding the status and nav bar
                val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
                systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
                systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
                systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false // Status & Navigation bars
                systemUiController.navigationBarDarkContentEnabled = true

                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(0.dp),
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the way to do that.. the thing is you have to follow this guide for display cutouts or notches : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/display-cutout

the rest of the code will be same and to take the container full screen after hiding the system bars you have to update your : `app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <style name="Theme.Gallery" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
         <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: for more discussion regarding this check this : [link](https://github.com/IacobIonut01/Gallery/discussions/136)